# Variables en NULL y 0 - en Variables en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una practica/proyecto en JAVA, donde las clases controladores funcionan muy bien por separado, pero tengo una falla entre esta conexión y el modulo de la interface del usuario, que es que me parece esta reseteando las variables de los campos donde el usuario puede ingresar: nombre aeropuerto, direccion, etc. 
Porque me estara tomando las variables del objeto aux de tipo Aeropuerto de tipo NULL y 0? Hace horas que estoy con esto y ya hice todo tipo de pruebas, pero no puedo encontrar el error.

**La salida por consola es:**
ID Aeropuerto=7 Aeropuerto [Nombre=, Direccion=[Pais=, Calle=, Numero=0, Ciudad=], Año Inauguracion=0, Capacidad=0
Cuenta con los siguientes aviones=
]

El aeropuerto es privado y tiene 10 socios

```
JButton okButton = new JButton("Guardar");
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    // ACA VA EL CODIGO DONDE GUARDAMOS LOS DATOS

                    String errores = "";

                    String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
                    String pais = txtPais.getText();
                    String calle = txtCalle.getText();
                    String numero = txtNumero.getText();
                    String ciudad = txtCiudad.getText();
                    String anioInauguracion = txtAnioInauguracion.getText();
                    String capacidad = txtCapacidad.getText();
                    String financiacion = "", discapacitados = "", numSocios = "";

                    if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
                        errores += " - El nombre no puede estar vacio \n";
                    }

                    if (pais.isEmpty()) {
                        errores += " - El pais no puede estar vacio \n";
                    }

                    if (calle.isEmpty()) {
                        errores += " - La calle no puede estar vacia \n";
                    }

                    if (numero.isEmpty()) {
                        errores += " - El numero no puede estar vacia \n";
                    } else {
                        if (!MetodosSueltos.validarNumeroEntero(numero)) {
                            errores += " - El numero no tiene el formato correcto \n";
                        }
                    }

                    if (ciudad.isEmpty()) {
                        errores += " - La ciudad no puede estar vacia \n";
                    }

                    if (anioInauguracion.isEmpty()) {
                        errores += " - El año de inauguracion puede estar vacia \n";
                    } else {
                        if (!MetodosSueltos.validarNumeroEntero(anioInauguracion)) {
                            errores += " - El año de inauguracion no tiene el formato correcto \n";
                        }
                    }

                    if (capacidad.isEmpty()) {
                        errores += " - La capacidad no puede estar vacia \n";
                    } else {
                        if (!MetodosSueltos.validarNumeroEntero(capacidad)) {
                            errores += " - La capacidad no tiene el formato correcto \n";
                        }
                    }

                    if (rdbPublico.isSelected()) {

                        financiacion = txtFinanciacion.getText();
                        discapacitados = txtDiscapacitados.getText();

                        if (financiacion.isEmpty()) {
                            errores += " - La financiacion no puede estar vacia \n";
                        } else {
                            if (!MetodosSueltos.validarNumeroReal(financiacion)) {
                                errores += " - La financiacion no tiene el formato correcto \n";
                            }
                        }

                        if (discapacitados.isEmpty()) {
                            errores += " - El numero de discapacitados no puede estar vacio \n";
                        } else {
                            if (!MetodosSueltos.validarNumeroEntero(discapacitados)) {
                                errores += " - El numero de discapacitados no tiene el formato correcto \n";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {

                        numSocios = txtNumSocios.getText();

                        if (numSocios.isEmpty()) {
                            errores += " - El numero de socios no puede estar vacio \n";
                        } else {
                            if (!MetodosSueltos.validarNumeroEntero(numSocios)) {
                                errores += " - El numero de socios no tiene el formato correcto \n";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (errores.isEmpty()) {

                        int numeroAeropuerto = Integer.parseInt(numero);
                        int anioInauguracioAeropuerto = Integer.parseInt(anioInauguracion);
                        int capacidadAeropuerto = Integer.parseInt(capacidad);

                        Aeropuerto aux;

                        Direccion dir = new Direccion(pais, calle, numeroAeropuerto, ciudad);

                        if (rdbPublico.isSelected()) {
                            double financiacionAeropuerto = Double.parseDouble(financiacion);
                            int discapacitadosAeropuerto = Integer.parseInt(discapacitados);


                            aux = new AeropuertoPublico(financiacionAeropuerto,
                                    discapacitadosAeropuerto,
                                    nombre,
                                    dir,
                                    anioInauguracioAeropuerto,
                                    capacidadAeropuerto);

                        } else {
                            int numSociosAeropuerto = Integer.parseInt(numSocios);
                            aux = new AeropuertoPrivado(numSociosAeropuerto,
                                    nombre,
                                    dir,
                                    anioInauguracioAeropuerto,
                                    capacidadAeropuerto);
                        }

                        try {
                            MetodosSueltos.escribirAeropuerto(aux);

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Aeropuerto creado correctamente",
                                    "Éxito",
                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    ex.getMessage(),
                                    "Error",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                errores,
                                "Error",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }


                }
```

// Metodo EscribirAeropuerto:

```
public static void leerAeropuertos() {

    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(VariablesGlobales.FICHERO_AEROPUERTOS))) {

        while (true) {
            Aeropuerto a = (Aeropuerto) ois.readObject();
            VariablesGlobales.aeropuertos.add(a);
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void escribirAeropuerto(Aeropuerto a) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { // EN CASO DE FALLO
                                                                                                // ARRIBA EL ERROR Y
                                                                                                // EL USUARIO VA A
                                                                                                // SER EL QUE
                                                                                                // PERSONALICE EL
                                                                                                // ERROR // QUE TIRE
                                                                                                // HACIA

    // La clase File representa un fichero o directorio de nuestro sistema de
    // archivos. También nos es
    // útil ya que puede pasarse como parámetro para las principales clases que
    // manejan ficheros, como
    // FileReader, FileInputStream, FileWriter, etc. Podemos pasarle un String con
    // la ruta del fichero, también
    // hay otros constructores. Estos son:

    File f = new File(VariablesGlobales.FICHERO_AEROPUERTOS);

    if (f.exists()) {
        MiObjectOutputStream oos = new MiObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(VariablesGlobales.FICHERO_AEROPUERTOS, true));
        oos.writeObject(a);
        oos.close();
    } else {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(VariablesGlobales.FICHERO_AEROPUERTOS));
        oos.writeObject(a);
        oos.close();
    }

    VariablesGlobales.aeropuertos.add(a);

    /*
     * File f = new File(VariablesGlobales.FICHERO_AEROPUERTOS); // if (f.exists())
     * {// SI EL FILE EXISTE USAMOS NUESTRA CLASE MiObjectOutputStream oos = new
     * MiObjectOutputStream( new
     * FileOutputStream(VariablesGlobales.FICHERO_AEROPUERTOS)); oos.writeObject(a);
     * oos.close(); } else { // CASO CONTRARIO QUE NO EXISTA, UTILIZAMOS LA CLASE DE
     * JAVA ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( new
     * FileOutputStream(VariablesGlobales.FICHERO_AEROPUERTOS)); oos.writeObject(a);
     * oos.close();
     * 
     * }
     * 
     * VariablesGlobales.aeropuertos.add(a);// CON ESTA LINEA EL FICHERO Y LA LISTA
     * TIENEN QUE ESTAR EN CONCORDANCIA
     */
}
```

//Clase Aeropuerto

```
public abstract class Aeropuerto implements Comparable<Aeropuerto> {

private String nombre;
private Direccion direccion;
private int anioInauguracion;
private int capacidad;
private final int CAPACIDAD_MAXIMA = 20;
private Avion[] aviones = new Avion[CAPACIDAD_MAXIMA];
private int numeroAviones;
private static int id_Autonumerado = 1;
private int id = id_Autonumerado;

public Aeropuerto() {
    this("", "", "", 0, "", 0, 0);

}

// CONSTRUCTOR 1
public Aeropuerto(String nombre, String pais, String calle, int numero, String ciudad, int anioInauguracion,
        int capacidad) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = new Direccion(pais, calle, numero, ciudad);
    this.anioInauguracion = anioInauguracion;
    this.capacidad = capacidad;
    this.aviones = new Avion[CAPACIDAD_MAXIMA];
    this.numeroAviones = 0;
    id_Autonumerado++;

}

// CONSTRUCTOR 2
public Aeropuerto(String nombre, Direccion direccion, int anioInauguracion, int capacidad) {
    this(nombre, direccion.getPais(), direccion.getCalle(), direccion.getNumero(), direccion.getCiudad(),
            anioInauguracion, capacidad);


}

@Override
public int compareTo(Aeropuerto a) {
    if (this.anioInauguracion > a.getAnioInauguracion()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.anioInauguracion < a.getAnioInauguracion()) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Aeropuerto other = (Aeropuerto) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}

public abstract void calcularGananciasTotales(double cantidadGanada);

public int getNumeroAviones() {
    return numeroAviones;
}

private String mostrarAviones() {
    String avionesCadena = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroAviones; i++) {
        if (this.aviones[i].isActivado()) { // SOLO MUESTRA LOS AVIONES ACTIVADOS
            avionesCadena += aviones[i] + "\n";
        }

    }
    return avionesCadena;
}

public void aniadirAvion(Avion avion) {
    if (numeroAviones <= CAPACIDAD_MAXIMA) {
        this.aviones[numeroAviones] = avion;
        numeroAviones++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Maxima cantidad de aviones permitidos");
    }

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public Direccion getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public int getAnioInauguracion() {
    return anioInauguracion;
}

public void setAnioInauguracion(int anioInauguracion) {
    this.anioInauguracion = anioInauguracion;
}

public int getCapacidad() {
    return capacidad;
}

public void setCapacidad(int capacidad) {
    this.capacidad = capacidad;
}

public final int aniosAbierto() {

    return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) - anioInauguracion;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID Aeropuerto=" + id + " Aeropuerto [Nombre=" + nombre + ", Direccion=" + direccion
            + ", Año Inauguracion=" + anioInauguracion + ", Capacidad=" + capacidad + "\n"
            + "Cuenta con los siguientes aviones=" + "\n" + mostrarAviones() + "]" + "\n";
}
```

}

Comment: tu método escribirAereopuerto para ver si es estático e intenta poner tu clase aereopuerto.

Comment: Ahi las añadi @RuslanLópez Gracias!!! Sigo en esto ajajaj

Comment: Interesante que Aereopuerto sea abstracta. Sus implementaciones implementan la interfaz serializable?

Comment: Si @RuslanLópez todas las interfaces heredan de Serializable! Que pensas que puede ser?

Comment: Si quieres puedo subir todo a mi GIT

Comment: sí, ewstaría chido. Por lo que veo está tomando todo con los valores por defecto, como si llamara al primer constructor.

Comment: Raramente pase todas las clases a netbeans y funciono. Creo que eclipse WindowBuiler tiene problemas. Que pensas?

Comment: típicas cosas de eclipse. Seguramente nunca actualizó la clase espués de compilarla con el consructor vacío.